# Assembly 8086 questions without mul and div

Tags: assembly

I have some question of assembly 8086 (without mul/div):

how to do this exercises without mul and div:

1) bx←bx×32C (1 line)

2) bx←bx×41 (5 lines)

3) bx←bx×63

4) bx←bx/16

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the question? [And what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

They're all a number of fairly simple shift/arithmetic operations, two (untested) implemented below with hints for the rest;

1) bx←bx×32C (1 line)

```
# A left shift by 5 positions is a multiplication by 32
shl $5, %ebx
```

2) bx←bx×41 (5 lines, clobbering eax)

```
# Add ebx + 8*ebx + 32*ebx = 41*ebx
mov %eax, %ebx
shl $3,   %ebx
add %eax, %ebx
shl $2,   %ebx
add %ebx, %eax
```

3) bx←bx×63

```
# Calculate 64*ebx - ebx = 63*ebx
```

4) bx←bx/16

```
# A shift right by 4 is a division by 16
```

Comment: 2) Intel syntax: | push eax | lea eax,[ebx+ebx*4] | shl eax,3 | add ebx,eax | pop eax |